# Move files from single folder to existing folders with names like file name

Tags: powershell

I have a source folder that will contain a bunch of pdf reports with a naming convention

`JOB XXXXXX (then some other not important stuff and a datestamp).pdf`

where XXXXXX is a reference number.

In a destination folder there are numerous folders named

`JOB XXXXXX (other not important info)`

What I am trying to do is to move any pdf in the source folder where the JOB XXXXXX part of the filename matches the JOB XXXXXX part of the folder in the destination folder and moves it to that folder with the matching name.

Here is the code i have so far, I just can't work out where I am going wrong:

```
$source = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\PDF TEST"
$destination = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\PDF TEST FOLDERS MOVE"
$filesToSearch = (Get-ChildItem $source -Filter *.pdf -Recurse) # | % {($_.name.split('')[0..1] -join ' ')})
$destLocations = Get-ChildItem $destination #| where-object {($_.name.split('')[0..1] -join ' ')} 

        Get-ChildItem $source -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
                if (($destLocations.name.split('')[0..1] -join ' ') -match ($filesToSearch.name.split('')[0..1] -join ' '))
    {
    
      Move-Item ($filestosearch.fullname | Out-String) -Destination ($destlocations | out-string) -Force

      }
      }
```

Comment: Is `XXXXXX` always numeric like `123456`? Is it always followed by some character like a space, hyphen or underscore before the next unimportant info? Is `XXXXXX` always 6 characters (or digits)?

Comment: Hi Theo, yes the XXXXXX is always numerical, always 6 digits and followed by a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this ***should*** work if my logic is right. Note the `-WhatIf` on `Move-Item`, test it and if you think is working as expected remove that switch.

```
$source = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\PDF TEST"
$destination = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\PDF TEST FOLDERS MOVE"

$filesToSearch = Get-ChildItem $source -Filter *.pdf -Recurse
$destLocations = Get-ChildItem $destination -Directory

foreach($file in $filesToSearch)
{
    $searchFolder = -join ($file.BaseName -split '(?=\s)')[0..1]
    # Example of how this looks:
    # -join ('JOB XXXXXX (then some other not important stuff and a datestamp).pdf' -split '(?=\s)')[0..1]
    # Returns: JOB XXXXXX

    $destFolder = $destLocations | Where-Object {$searchFolder -match $_.Name}

    if(-not $destFolder)
    {
        "No folders found matching $searchFolder"
        continue
    }

    # Make sure here that there is only 1 Destination Folder    
    if($destFolder.count -gt 1)
    {
        Write-Warning "More than one folder found for $searchFolder"
        continue
    }

    "- Match found"
    "- File: {0}" -f $file.Name
    "- Destination Folder: {0}" -f $destFolder.Name
    ""

    $file | Move-Item -Destination $destFolder -WhatIf
}
```

I also added this to make sure you are matching what was expected, though this can be safely removed once you confirm it works :)

```
"- Match found"
"- File: {0}" -f $file.Name
"- Destination Folder: {0}" -f $destFolder.Name
```

Comment: Right, i've just tried it and it almost works - the problem i can see is that the folder names contain text after the XXXXX so it doesn't exact match the split filename.

Result: "No folders found matching Job XXXXX" etc...

Answer (score 0):

I've tweaked Santiago's code and found the solution which now works:

```
$source = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\PDF TEST"
$destination = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\PDF TEST FOLDERS MOVE"

$filesToSearch = Get-ChildItem $source -Filter *.pdf -Recurse
$destLocations = Get-ChildItem $destination -Directory

foreach($file in $filesToSearch)
{
$searchFolder = -join ($file.BaseName -split '(?=\s)')[0..1]
# Example of how this looks:
# -join ('JOB XXXXXX (then some other not important stuff and a datestamp).pdf' - 
split '(?=\s)')[0..1]
# Returns: JOB XXXXXX

$destFolder = $destLocations | Where-Object {$searchFolder -match 
$_.Name.Substring(0, 10)}
$moveto = $destination + '\' + $destFolder

if(-not $destFolder)
{
    "No folders found matching $searchFolder"
    continue
}

# Make sure here that there is only 1 Destination Folder    
if($destFolder.count -gt 1)
{
    Write-Warning "More than one folder found for $searchFolder"
    continue
}

"- Match found"
"- File: {0}" -f $file.Name
"- Destination Folder: {0}" -f $destFolder.Name
""

$file | Move-Item -Destination $moveto #-WhatIf
}
```